Google sheets query not returning words with special characters
So I don't know how to explain my problem very well, so I'm going to make an example, I think this is the best way to understand it, but basically I'm trying to return orders that match words in a list, and those words can contain special characters, example below:
I have a list of references like:



A




Grass


Dirt


Water


Grass+



Now I have a list of orders like:



B
C




1
Grass


2
Grass+


3
Potato


4
Grass+


5
Water



Now what I want to do is query though the orders list, and get all the orders that match the list of references, so what i did is:
=QUERY(
    B1:C,
    "SELECT Col1, Col2
    WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 MATCHES '"&TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;A1:A)&"' ORDER BY Col1 ASC",0
)

This returns me this:



D
E




1
Grass


5
Water



Instead of this:



D
E




1
Grass


2
Grass+


4
Grass+


5
Water



Why is the "Grass" with the + in the end being ignored? is there a way to resolve this problem? Am i doing something wrong?
Thanks for helping guys!


Certain characters (* , + , ?, ^ , $) needs to escaped since they have a meaning within regex match. Try changing this
TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;A1:A)

to
substitute(TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;A1:A);"+";"\+")

Alternative formula
=sort(filter(B:C;xmatch(C:C;A:A)))


That make total sense, i forgot completly that i might had to escape those characters, thank you so much for your help, that worked perfectly!
